# How to implement a Nested List Iterator

Tags: java, list, algorithm, iterator, nested-lists

I was asked this question during an interview:

"How can I implement a custom nested list iterator?"

Method `next()` should return the first element of each list firstly, then second element and so on so forth.

*Input example*:

```
[[1,2,3],[4,5],[6],[],[7,8,9]]
```

*Output*:

```
[1,4,6,7,2,5,8,3,9]
```

*Stub-Code*:

```
public class CustomListIterator implements Iterator<Integer> {
    
    public CustomListIterator(List<List<Integer>> nestedList) {
        
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        
    }
    
    @Override
    public Integer next() {
        
    }
}
```

How it could be implemented?

Answer (score 0):

You can achieve that by utilizing the combination of `ListIterator` and `Iterator`. This approach allows you to free yourself from the necessity to maintain any positions.

The general idea is to create a *list of iterators* and a *listIterator* that would iterate over these lists.

Method `hasNext()` performs iteration over the list and checks whether it has at least one not exhausted iterator.

Method `next()` is a bit more elaborate. Firstly, it will try "reset" the *listIterator* from the position behind the last element to the position before the first element of the list.

Then inside the loop, it'll examine the next *iterator* in the list and if this *iterator* is exhausted it'll get removed. In order to make this operation fast, iterators are stored in a `LinkedList`. And if the element was found, it will be returned.

To treat the situation when "empty" iterator appear at the end of the list and *listIterator* reaches the last position, but there could a few more unvisited iterators in the list, an additional check is placed at the very end of the loop.

In the implementation below, I've used streams inside `hasNext()` and constructor for the purpose of conciseness. Even if you are not very comfortable with streams, the overall logic should clear, and you can easily substitute it with streams.

```
public class CustomListIterator<T> implements Iterator<T> {
    private List<Iterator<T>> iterators;
    private ListIterator<Iterator<T>> listIterator;
    
    public CustomListIterator(List<List<T>> nestedList) {
        this.iterators = nestedList.stream()
            .map(List::iterator)
            .collect(Collectors.toCollection(LinkedList::new));
        
        this.listIterator = iterators.listIterator();
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {        
        return iterators.stream().anyMatch(Iterator::hasNext);
    }
    
    @Override
    public T next() {
        if (!iterators.isEmpty() && !listIterator.hasNext()) tryReset();

        while (!iterators.isEmpty() && listIterator.hasNext()) {
            Iterator<T> current = listIterator.next();

            if (!current.hasNext()) {
                listIterator.remove(); // removing exhausted iterator
            } else {
                return current.next();
            }
    
            if (!listIterator.hasNext()) tryReset();
        }
        throw new IllegalStateException();
    }
    
    private void tryReset() {
        while (listIterator.hasPrevious()) {
            listIterator.previous();
        }
    }
}
```

`main()` - demo

```
public static void main(String[] args) {
    List<List<Integer>> numbers =
        List.of(List.of(1, 4, 6, 7),
                List.of(),
                List.of(2, 5),
                List.of(3));

    CustomListIterator<Integer> nestedIterator = new CustomListIterator<>(numbers);
    
    while (nestedIterator.hasNext()) {
        System.out.print(nestedIterator.next() + "\t");
    }
}
```

**Output**

```
1   2   3   4   5   6   7
```

Answer (score 0):

To implement an Iterator, we need a cursor to keep track of which element we are currently on. Depending on the underlying data structure said cursor could be either an index or a pointer and it will be used to progress from one element to another. This is done in the next() method which returns the current element and the cursor advances to the next element.

Since in your question you're asking for a custom iterator for a generic list (not specifically an ArrayList or a LinkedList); I decided to use as a cursor an int index in order to point to elements of both data structure.

To answer your question, I've pictured your list of lists as a matrix with rows of different lengths, where we first iterate through the rows of the current column (outer list cursor) and then we move to the next column (inner list or sublist cursor).

```
class CustomListIteratorVert implements Iterator<Integer> {

    private List<List<Integer>> nestedList;
    private int listCur, subListCur;

    //value to understand when the iteration has completed since the "column" cursor has reached its end
    private int maxSublistSize;

    public CustomListIteratorVert(List<List<Integer>> nestedList) {
        this.nestedList = nestedList;
        this.listCur = 0;
        this.subListCur = 0;

        //Identifying the greates size among the sublists
        this.maxSublistSize = nestedList.stream().map(list -> list.size()).max(Integer::compareTo).orElse(0);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean hasNext() {
        //If the sublist cursor hasn't exceeded the last "column" then there are further elements to iterate (worst case scenario: only the current element)
        return subListCur < maxSublistSize;
    }

    @Override
    public Integer next() {
        //If the last column has been exceeded (no further elements to iterate) then no value is returned
        if (subListCur == maxSublistSize) {
            return null;
        }

        //Saving the current value to return
        Integer value = nestedList.get(listCur).get(subListCur);

        //Incrementing the outer list cursor to point to the next "row" (matrix visualization)
        if (listCur < nestedList.size() - 1) {
            listCur++;
        } else {
            //Incrementing the sublist cursors to point to the next column and resetting the "row" index (matrix visualization)
            subListCur++;
            listCur = 0;
        }

        // In case there are still elements left and the current cursors do not point to an existing element (sublist cursor greater than the sublist's size)
        // then these "empty spots" are skipped as long as the last column hasn't been exceeded or the next element hasn't been met
        while (subListCur < maxSublistSize && subListCur >= nestedList.get(listCur).size()) {
            if (listCur < nestedList.size() - 1) {
                listCur++;
            } else {
                subListCur++;
                listCur = 0;
            }
        }

        return value;
    }
}

public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        //Added extra empty lists to create more "empty sposts"
        List<List<Integer>> nestedList = new ArrayList<>(List.of(List.of(1, 2, 3), List.of(4, 5), List.of(6), List.of(), List.of(7, 8, 9), List.of(), List.of()));

        System.out.println("------------ Iterator ------------");
        CustomListIteratorVert custIt = new CustomListIteratorVert(nestedList);
        while (custIt.hasNext()) {
            System.out.println(custIt.next());
        }

        
        System.out.println("\n\n------------ Flattened List foreach loop ------------");
        List<Integer> listFlattenedFor = new ArrayList<>();
        for (List<Integer> sublist : nestedList) {
            listFlattenedFor.addAll(sublist);
        }
        listFlattenedFor.forEach(i -> System.out.println(i));


        System.out.println("\n\n------------ Flattened List Stream ------------");
        List<Integer> listFlattenedStream = new ArrayList<>();
        nestedList.stream().forEach(list -> listFlattenedStream.addAll(list));
        listFlattenedFor.forEach(i -> System.out.println(i));
    }
}
```

### **EDIT**

My main contains also the flattening of your list because it had been asked before the question edits.

### **Warning**

the second flattening approach with a stateful lambda should be used **only and absolutely** with non-parallel streams. Furthermore, the simple for loop approach not only is safer but also much more efficient. I've just posted also the stream approach only to show different ways of achieving the same result.